# jquery - pass parameters when using .call()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you pass parameters to a function when using `.call()` in Javascript?

When I pass parameters they are always undefined in the callback function

EDIT (an example):

I will have an options object in my plugin:

```
var options = {

errorCallback : function( errors ) {}

}
```

I will call this from my plugin like this:

```
var errors = "Test error list";
configs.errorCallback.call(errors);
```

I will initialise my plugin like this

```
 $('#plugin-element').myPlugin(
       { 
           'errorCallback' : function errorrCallbackFunction( errors ) {
                   console.log(errors) //always undefined
               }
       }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you do that doesn't work?

Comment: Callback function? Which callback function?
And .call() is not specific to jQuery, it is a JavaScript function (or, to be more precise, it is a method of the function object).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The first argument of call is the 'this' of the function. If you want to pass the variable as argument start from the second one.

```
configs.errorCallback.call(undefined, errors);
```

Here is the documentation:  [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Using_call_to_invoke_a_function_and_specifying_the_context_for_'this')

Answer (score 10):

```
configs.errorCallback.call(errors);
```

This isn't necessary.  You only need to use `call` if you want to set the *context* of the function call.  That means the value of `this` within the callback.

If you don't want to set `this`, then you can just call the function as you normally would:

```
configs.errorCallback(errors);
```

If you do want to set `this`, then you need to set it as the first parameter to `call`.  Subsequent parameters are passed on to the function.

For example:

```
var configs = {
    errorCallback : function( errors ) {}
};
configs.errorCallback.call(configs, errors);
```

Within `errorCallback`, you can access `configs` using the keyword `this`.